# Quaternions rotation has a weird behaviour (Haskell OpenGL)

Tags: haskell, opengl, quaternions

I've been following the [Haskell OpenGL tutorial](https://wiki.haskell.org/OpenGLTutorial1).
Rotations in a 3D space intrigued me so I started learning about Euler angles and finally, quaternions.

I wanted to implement my own function using quaternions to perform a rotation (on a cube), I've based myself on those two papers: [mostly this one](https://lucidar.me/en/quaternions/quaternions-rotations/) and [this one](http://danceswithcode.net/engineeringnotes/quaternions/quaternions.html).

My function works fine when I'm performing a rotation on only one axis, but when I do it on X and Y for example, the cube start to randomly go forward and being "blocked" when it rotates.

[Video of the cube performing rotation on XY](https://streamable.com/l09dia).

When I set the three axis (X, Y, Z), it zooms even more (but doesn't have that weird blocking thing): [video](https://streamable.com/pob5zg).

Here is the code of my program:

*Here is the main file that creates a window, set idle function and outputs result of rotation by angle A on the screen where A is increment by 0.05 at each frames.*

```
module Main (main) where
import Core
import Utils
import Data.IORef
import Graphics.UI.GLUT
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL

main :: IO ()
main = do
    createAWindow "177013"
    mainLoop

createAWindow :: [Char] -> IO ()
createAWindow windowName = do
    (procName, _args) <- getArgsAndInitialize
    createWindow windowName
    initialDisplayMode $= [DoubleBuffered]
    angle <- newIORef 0.0
    delta <- newIORef 0.05
    displayCallback $= (start angle)
    reshapeCallback $= Just reshape
    keyboardMouseCallback $= Just keyboardMouse
    idleCallback $= Just (idle angle delta)

reshape :: ReshapeCallback
reshape size = do
             viewport $= (Position 0 0, size)
             postRedisplay Nothing


keyboardMouse :: KeyboardMouseCallback
keyboardMouse _ _ _ _ = return ()

idle :: IORef GLfloat -> IORef GLfloat -> IdleCallback
idle angle delta = do
           d <- get delta
           a <- get angle
           angle $~! (+d)
           postRedisplay Nothing
start :: IORef GLfloat -> DisplayCallback
start angle = do
            clear [ColorBuffer]
            loadIdentity
            a <- get angle
            let c = rotate3f (0, 0, 0) [X,Y,Z] a $ cube3f 0.2 -- here I'm rotating on X, Y and Z axis
            draw3f Quads c CCyan
            flush
            swapBuffers
                where
```

*Here is the core file where the rotation function is defined (with a few other ones). I added some comments as it's probably some low quality haskell code.*

```
module Core (draw3f, vertex3f, rotate3f, translate3f, rotate3d, Colors(..), Axes(..)) where

import Control.Lens
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL

data Axes = X | Y | Z
            deriving Eq
data Colors = CRed | CGreen | CBlue | CYellow | CWhite | CMagenta | CCyan | CBlack | CNone | CPreset
              deriving Eq


rotate3f :: (GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat) -> [Axes] -> GLfloat -> [(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)] -> [(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)]
rotate3f _ _ _ [] = []
rotate3f _ [] _ _ = []
rotate3f o axes a p = let p' = translate3f p u -- translation if I don't want to rotate it by the origin
                          q = cos a' : ((\x -> if x `elem` axes then sin a' else 0) <$> [X,Y,Z]) -- if the axe is set then its related component is equal to sin theta/2, otherwise it will be 0
                          q' = q !! 0 : (negate <$> (tail q)) -- quaternion inversion
                      in translate3f ((rotate q q') <$> p') [(0,0,0),o] -- rotate and translate again to put the object where it belongs
                          where
                              a' = (a * (pi / 180)) / 2 -- convert to radians and divide by 2 as all q components takes theta/2
                              u :: [(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)]
                              u = [o,(0,0,0)]
                              rotate :: [GLfloat] -> [GLfloat] -> (GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat) -> (GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)
                              rotate q q' (x,y,z) = let p = [0,x,y,z]
                                                        qmul q1 q2 = [(q1 !! 0) * (q2 !! 0) - (q1 !! 1) * (q2 !! 1) - (q1 !! 2) * (q2 !! 2) - (q1 !! 3) * (q2 !! 3),
                                                                      (q1 !! 0) * (q2 !! 1) + (q1 !! 1) * (q2 !! 0) + (q1 !! 2) * (q2 !! 3) - (q1 !! 3) * (q2 !! 2),
                                                                      (q1 !! 0) * (q2 !! 2) - (q1 !! 1) * (q2 !! 3) + (q1 !! 2) * (q2 !! 0) + (q1 !! 3) * (q2 !! 1),
                                                                      (q1 !! 0) * (q2 !! 3) + (q1 !! 1) * (q2 !! 2) - (q1 !! 2) * (q2 !! 1) + (q1 !! 3) * (q2 !! 0)]
                                                        p' = qmul (qmul q p) q'
                                                    in (p' !! 1, p' !! 2, p' !! 3)


                    
translate3f :: [(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)] -> [(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)] -> [(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)]
translate3f p [(ax,ay,az),(bx,by,bz)] = map (\(x,y,z) -> (x + (bx - ax), y + (by - ay), z + (bz - az))) p



draw3f :: PrimitiveMode -> [(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)] -> Colors -> IO()
draw3f shape points color = renderPrimitive shape $ mapM_ (\(x,y,z) -> vertex3f x y z color) points

vertex3f :: GLfloat -> GLfloat -> GLfloat -> Colors -> IO()
vertex3f x y z c = do
                 if c /= CPreset
                    then color $ Color3 (c' ^. _1) (c' ^. _2) ((c' ^. _3) :: GLfloat)
                 else return ()
                 vertex $ Vertex3 x y z
                     where
                         c' :: (GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)
                         c' = case c of CRed -> (1,0,0)
                                        CGreen -> (0,1,0)
                                        CBlue -> (0,0,1)
                                        CYellow -> (1,1,0)
                                        CMagenta -> (1,0,1)
                                        CCyan -> (0,1,1)
                                        CBlack -> (0,0,0)
                                        _ -> (1,1,1)
```

*And here is the utils file where there's just the definition of the cube, from the Haskell OpenGL tutorial*

```
module Utils (cube3f) where

import Core
import Graphics.UI.GLUT
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL

cube3f :: GLfloat -> [(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)]
cube3f w = [( w, w, w), ( w, w,-w), ( w,-w,-w), ( w,-w, w),
            ( w, w, w), ( w, w,-w), (-w, w,-w), (-w, w, w),
            ( w, w, w), ( w,-w, w), (-w,-w, w), (-w, w, w),
            (-w, w, w), (-w, w,-w), (-w,-w,-w), (-w,-w, w),
            ( w,-w, w), ( w,-w,-w), (-w,-w,-w), (-w,-w, w),
            ( w, w,-w), ( w,-w,-w), (-w,-w,-w), (-w, w,-w)]
```

Finally, if it can helps people to see if there's a problem in my algorithms, here are some *rotation samples* using my function:

Rotation at 90°, of point (1, 2, 3) on X axis around point (0, 0, 0) (origin) gives: `(0.99999994,-3.0,2.0)`

Same rotation but on X & Y axis gives: `(5.4999995,-0.99999994,-0.49999988)`

Same rotation again but on X, Y and Z axis gives: `(5.9999995,1.9999999,3.9999995)`

Comment: The second paper about rotations by quaternions that you point to has this sentence: “(x̂, ŷ, ẑ) is a **unit** vector that defines the axis of rotation.”. So the quaternion has to be normalized, the sum of components squared being equal to 1. So for example if you have all 3 axis involved, it has to be (cos θ/2, r3*sin θ/2, r3*sin θ/2, r3*sin θ/2) where r3 is the reciprocal of the square root of 3. This is how I would explain that the rotation results you mention at the end of your post fail to conserve the length of the vector when several axis are involved.

Comment: @jpmarinier thanks for the detailed answer. And if I have for example 2 axis involved (y & x for example), the Z component should be zeroed ?

Comment: If you have just axes X and Y enabled, it should be (cos θ/2, r2*sin θ/2, r2*sin θ/2, 0) where r2 is the reciprocal of the square root of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second paper about rotations by quaternions that you point to has this sentence:

*“(x̂, ŷ, ẑ) is a unit vector that defines the axis of rotation.”*.

So the quaternion has to be normalized, the sum of components squared being equal to 1.

So for example if you have all 3 axis involved, it has to be (cos θ/2, r3*sin θ/2, r3*sin θ/2, r3*sin θ/2) where r3 is the reciprocal of the square root of 3. This is how I would explain that the rotation results you mention at the end of your post fail to conserve the length of the vector when several axis are involved.

The critical piece is thus this line in function `rotate3f`:

```
q = cos a' : ((\x -> if x `elem` axes then sin a' else 0) <$> [X,Y,Z])
```

where a normalization factor is missing.

Your code offers a number of opportunities for readability improvement. You might consider using [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) for further details.

A major concern is the fact that the source code lines are too wide. If the reader has to use an horizontal slider, it is much more difficult to understand the code and find the bugs. Below, I will try to avoid going beyond 80 characters width.

First, we need some quaternion infrastructure:

```
{-#  LANGUAGE  ScopedTypeVariables  #-}
{-#  LANGUAGE  ExplicitForAll       #-}

type GLfloat   = Float
type GLfloatV3 = (GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)
type QuatFloat = [GLfloat]

data Axes =  X | Y | Z  deriving  Eq

qmul :: QuatFloat -> QuatFloat -> QuatFloat
qmul  [qa0, qa1, qa2, qa3]  [qb0, qb1, qb2, qb3] =
    [
       qa0*qb0 - qa1*qb1 - qa2*qb2 - qa3*qb3 ,
       qa0*qb1 + qa1*qb0 + qa2*qb3 - qa3*qb2 ,
       qa0*qb2 - qa1*qb3 + qa2*qb0 + qa3*qb1 ,
       qa0*qb3 + qa1*qb2 - qa2*qb1 + qa3*qb0
    ]
qmul _ _  =  error "Quaternion length differs from 4"

qconj :: QuatFloat -> QuatFloat
qconj q = (head q) : (map negate (tail q)) -- q-conjugation

rotate :: [GLfloat] -> [GLfloat] -> GLfloatV3 -> GLfloatV3
rotate q q' (x,y,z) = let  p             = [0, x,y,z]
                           [q0,q1,q2,q3] = qmul (qmul q p) q'
                      in  (q1, q2, q3)
```

Note that the idea of defining ad hoc types not only allows for reduced code width, but that also gives extra flexibility. If some day you decide to represent quaternions by some other data structure which is more efficient than a plain list, it can be done while leaving the client code unchanged.

Next, the rotation code proper. Function `rotQuat0` is your initial algorithm, which reproduces the numerical results mentioned at the end of your question. Function `rotQuat1` is the modified version giving a 1-normalized quaternion.

```
-- original code:
rotQuat0 :: [Axes] -> GLfloat -> QuatFloat
rotQuat0 axes angle = let  fn x = if (x `elem` axes) then (sin angle) else 0
                      in   (cos angle) : (map fn [X,Y,Z])

-- modified code:
rotQuat1 :: [Axes] -> GLfloat -> QuatFloat
rotQuat1 axes angle = let  corr = 1.0 / sqrt (fromIntegral (length axes))
                           fn x = if (x `elem` axes) then corr*(sin angle) else 0
                      in   (cos angle) : (map fn [X,Y,Z])
```

Code using `rotQuat1`:

```
rotate3f :: GLfloatV3 -> [Axes] -> GLfloat -> [GLfloatV3] -> [GLfloatV3]
rotate3f _ _ _ [] = []
rotate3f _ [] _ _ = []
rotate3f org axes degθ pts =
    let   -- convert to radians and divide by 2, as all q components take θ/2
          a' = (degθ * (pi / 180)) / 2
          u :: [GLfloatV3]
          u = [org, (0,0,0)]
          -- translation if I don't want to rotate it by the origin
          p' = translate3f pts u
          -- if the axis is set, then its related component is
          -- equal to sin θ/2, otherwise it will be zero
          ---- q = cos a' : ((\x -> if x `elem` axes then sin a' else 0) <$> [X,Y,Z])
          q = rotQuat1 axes a'  -- modified version
          q' = qconj q
         -- rotate and translate again to put the object where it belongs
    in   translate3f ((rotate q q') <$> p') [(0,0,0), org] 

             
translate3f :: [GLfloatV3] -> [GLfloatV3] -> [GLfloatV3]
translate3f  pts  [(ax,ay,az), (bx,by,bz)]  =
    let   dx = bx - ax
          dy = by - ay
          dz = bz - az
    in   map  (\(x,y,z) -> (x + dx, y + dy, z + dz))  pts
```

### Testing code:

```
sqNorm3 :: GLfloatV3 -> GLfloat
sqNorm3 (x,y,z) = x*x + y*y +z*z

printAsLines :: Show α => [α] -> IO ()
printAsLines xs = mapM_  (putStrLn . show)  xs

main = do
    let  pt  = (1,2,3) :: GLfloatV3
         pt1 = rotate3f (0,0,0) [X]     90 [pt]
         pt2 = rotate3f (0,0,0) [X,Y]   90 [pt]
         pt3 = rotate3f (0,0,0) [X,Y,Z] 90 [pt]
         pts = map head [pt1, pt2, pt3]
         ptN = map sqNorm3 pts
    printAsLines pts
    putStrLn " "
    printAsLines ptN
```

Let's check that with function `rotQuat1`, the squared norm of your initial (1,2,3) input vector (that is 1+4+9=13)  remains unchanged, as befits a proper rotation:

```
$ ghc opengl00.hs -o ./opengl00.x && ./opengl00.x
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( opengl00.hs, opengl00.o )
Linking ./opengl00.x ...

(0.99999994,-3.0,2.0)
(3.6213198,-0.62132025,0.70710695)
(2.5773501,0.84529924,2.5773501)

14.0
13.999995
13.999998
$
```

Unfortunately I don't have enough time to install the OpenGL infrastructure and reproduce the animation. Please let us know whether this fixes the whole thing.

Comment: Please don't teach beginners that type synonyms provide an abstraction barrier—they don't. That's what newtypes are for.

Comment: Your solution works fine thanks :), when I rotate on X, Y and Z there's no bugs and works as expected. However, with X&Y, the cube doesn't go forward anymore but still "blocks" itself as on the previous video. Is this a normal behaviour ? [video here](https://streamable.com/qmb0zu)